# How reactive are reduced antioxidant molecules?

Tags: metabolism

When antioxidant molecules stabilize free radicals, they themselves become unstable and reactive but to a lesser degree. How reactive are these reduced antioxidant molecules? And what substance stabilizes reduced antioxidants?

Comment: How do you measure "reactiveness"?

Comment: Shouldn't this be better suited for http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/?